# Why I get Segmantation fault core dump while exe

Tags: c99

Hi I'm trying to do a programm that given a word and a char in input and stored it in an array create a list where it stores the strings btw the first and the second recursion of the char.
for example if i give you the world "albaniamicaoapa" and the char "a" it should create a list containing the first node the string "lb", the second node the string "mic",the third the string "p". And then I should print them in different lines.
I cannot understand where am I wrong, hope you can help. thx in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 4
#define MAX_LEN 30

typedef struct node {
    char val[MAX];
    struct node * next;
} node_t;

int main (){

    char word[MAX_LEN], ch;
    int len, i, many=0,j=0;

    printf("Write a word: \n");
    fgets(word, MAX_LEN, stdin);
    printf("Write a char: \n");
    scanf("%c", &ch);

    len = strlen(word);

    node_t *head = NULL;
    head = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    head->next = NULL;

    many = 2*(len-1);

    printf ("%d\n", many);

    node_t *current = head;
    node_t *test = head;
    test = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    test->next = NULL;
    strcpy(test->val, "A");

    //creation nodes of the list

    for (i=0; i < len; i++){
        current->next = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        current = current->next;
        current->next = NULL; 
    }

    //positioning at the head

    current = head;

    for (i=0; i < many; i++){
        if (word[i] == ch){
            i++;
            while (word[i] != ch){
                current->val[j] = word[i];
                j++;
                i++;
            }
            current = current->next;
            strcpy (current->val, "A");
            current = current->next;
            j=0;
        }
    }

    current = head;

    while (current->next != NULL) {
        if (current->val != test->val)
            printf("%s\n", current->val);
        current = current->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question -- it's difficult to know what you're saying here.

Comment: Define a subprogram that recives a string s and a character ch (and any other parameters
deemed necessary), return to the calling environment a list whose nodes store strings consisting of
characters that in s are between two occurrences of ch (these occurrences excluded). Such strings, if they exist,
have a predefined maximum size N. If s does not contain two occurrences of the character ch,
the subroutine returns an empty list.
It is ensured that, if ch is present at least twice in s, the number of characters between the two occurrences
never exceed the default length N.